# error using dependencyResolutionManagement in nuild.gradle in Android-Studio

Tags: android, gradle, dependencies, build.gradle

I try to add the dependencyResolutionManagement block to my build.gradle file.
I use this code in my `build.gradle` file:

```
plugins {
    id 'com.android.application'
}

android {
    compileSdkVersion 30
    buildToolsVersion "30.0.3"

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.example.findyourtimetable"
        minSdkVersion 24
        targetSdkVersion 30
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"

        testInstrumentationRunner "androidx.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }

    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android-optimize.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
    compileOptions {
        sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
        targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
    }

    dependencyResolutionManagement {

        repositoriesMode.set(RepositoriesMode.FAIL_ON_PROJECT_REPOS)
        repositories {
            google()
        }
    }

}


dependencies {

    implementation 'androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.3.0'
    implementation 'com.google.android.material:material:1.3.0'
    implementation 'androidx.constraintlayout:constraintlayout:2.0.4'
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.+'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.ext:junit:1.1.2'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.3.0'

    def fragment_version = "1.5.5"
    implementation "androidx.fragment:fragment:$fragment_version"

}
```

I have the following error :

```
Build file '...\app\build.gradle' line: 5

A problem occurred evaluating project ':app'.
> No signature of method: build_2qy3qm6nv25wc6g469gv6z2jt.android() is applicable for argument types: (build_2qy3qm6nv25wc6g469gv6z2jt$_run_closure1) values: [build_2qy3qm6nv25wc6g469gv6z2jt$_run_closure1@35f3e998]

* Try:
Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output. Run with --scan to get full insights.
```

I tried to change the location of the dependencyResolutionManagement block but the function is not recognize.

I don't know what to do to solve this problem
thanks in advance for any help

Answer (score 1):

You should add

```
dependencyResolutionManagement {
    repositoriesMode.set(RepositoriesMode.FAIL_ON_PROJECT_REPOS)
    repositories {
        google()
    }
}
```

into your `settings.gradle` file. You can take a look an example [here](https://github.com/android/nowinandroid/blob/main/settings.gradle.kts) from the nowinandroid app github repo.